# How to optimize mysql query to get count from json column which have huge data

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a query to find the count of rejected serialNos for different reasons. I need to find each reason count within a date limit.I have 3 tables say:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default           |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | 
| client_id        | int(11)      |YES   | MUL | NULL              |                 
| tc_date          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |                
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------------
mysql> desc job_order_finish_product_serial_no;
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----+
| Field                        | Type         | Null | Key | Default|
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----| 
id                           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL   |
| serial_no                    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL   |
| specification                | json         | YES  |     | NULL   |
| client_id                    | int(11)      |YES   | MUL | NULL   |
| tc_id                        | int(11)     | YES  |  MUL   | NULL |
| job_order_finish_products_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL   |
---------------------------------+-------------+-------+----+-------
```

In specification column my sample data looks like

```
    "Leakage":{
       "time":"2021-09-20 10:00:00",
       "status":"completed",
       "rework":[],
       "user":{
            "name":"xyz",
             "id":1
        }
     },
    "Thickness":{
       "time":"2021-09-20 10:00:00",
       "status":"rejected",
       "rework":[],
       "user":{
            "name":"xyz",
             "id":1
        }
     },
    "Diameter":{
       "time":null,
       "status":"pending",
       "rework":[],
       "user":{
        }
     },
    "Bung":{
       "time":null,
       "status":"pending",
       "rework":[],
       "user":{
       }
     }
}
```

For each serial_no in job_order_finish_product_serial_no, the specification should look like the above snippet. I need to get a count of each reason rejected serial_nos count within a date range. job_order_finish_product_serial_no row count was 2251543 rows.My count query is

```
select  tc.tc_date,
    (
        SELECT  count(serial_no)
            from  nucleus.job_order_finish_product_serial_no jfps
            where  jfps.tc_id=tc.id
              and  specification ->> "$.Thickness.status" = "rejected"
              and  client_id = 154
    ) as rejected_thickness,
    (
        SELECT  count(serial_no)
            from  nucleus.job_order_finish_product_serial_no jfps
            where  jfps.tc_id=tc.id
              and  specification ->> "$.Leakage.status" = "rejected"
              and  client_id = 154
    ) as rejected_leakage,
    (
        SELECT  count(serial_no)
            from  nucleus.job_order_finish_product_serial_no jfps
            where  jfps.tc_id=tc.id
              and  specification ->> "$.Bung.status" = "rejected"
              and  client_id = 154
    ) as rejected_bung
    from  nucleus.tc_details tc
    inner join  nucleus.job_order_finish_product_serial_no jfps
         ON jfps.tc_id=tc.id
    inner join  nucleus.job_order_finish_products jofp
         ON jofp.id=jfps.job_order_finish_products_id
    where  tc.tc_date between '2021-09-18 00:00:00'
                          AND '2021-09-22 23:59:59'
      and  tc.client_id=154
      and  jofp.client_id=154
      and  jfps.client_id=154
    group by  job_order_finish_product_id,tc.tc_date;
```

Output:

```
data        rejected_thickness  rejected_bung  rejected_leakage rejected_diameter
21-09-2021  2                   10             23               3
```

with the above query each subquery taking 2 min to give the result and the entire query taking almost taking 10min. Is there any way to optimize the query? Thank you!

Comment: Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  In particular, it shows the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

- Indexes that may help:

  ```
  jfps, jofp: INDEX(tc_id, client_id)   -- or in the opposite order
  tc: INDEX(client_id, tc_date, id)
  ```
- I prefer this way to write date range tests:

  ```
        date >= '2021-09-18'
    AND date  < '2021-09-18' + INTERVAL 4 DAY
  ```
- `JOIN` with a 'derived' table might be faster than 3 subqueries
- unless `count(serial_no)` is needed for excluding NULL values of `serial_no`, use `COUNT(*)`.

Something like

```
SELECT ...
        SUM(jfps.specification ->> "$.Leakage.status" = "rejected")
              as rejected_leakage,
        SUM(...) as ...,
        SUM(...) as ...,
    ...
    JOIN nucleus.job_order_finish_product_serial_no AS jfps
           ON jfps.tc_id = tc.id
    WHERE ...
        AND jfps.client_id = 154
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but there are some points which I don't understand i.e.those 3 sub queries accessing data from the same table.So, i don't know how join may help in this case. If you don't mind can you change the query by using `join` here

Comment: @KASIBHARGAVI - see if my addition helps.